# how to use tailwind CSS?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, plugins, tailwind-css

when writing a class in react jsx, the class hint does not come out.
how to make it so that if there is a class in the parent, change the child elements as it would be with the help of group.

1.the class hint from tailwind intellisense does not work here in jsx files

```
<h1 className="text-white w-?"></h1>
```

2.here, if the parent has an active class, p should turn red.

```
<div className="w-[300px] active">
   <p className="active.text-red-500/50">Text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `text-red-500/50` will work without adding the parent class.  You shouldn't need "parent" classes in TW.

Comment: @jmargolisvt I wrote for an example, I need to be able to change child elements with the active class.

Comment: You hardcoded `active` here but it's really conditional.  You don't need the parent class at all in TW.  On your `p` element, use a conditional className like this: className={\`${isActive ? 'text-red-500/50' : ''}\`}